# Can't understand regular expression in Javascript when match dates

Tags: javascript

so.. this is a part of an answer code to detect Hours and mintues in a given time

```
function scheduleMeeting(startTime,durationMinutes) { 
    var [ , meetingStartHour, meetingStartMinutes ] = startTime.match(/^(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})$/) || [];
...
}
```

What is this `(/^(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})$/)` referring to? It is really driving me crazy...

Comment: It's likely matching hours and minutes (either X:XX or XX:XX). because `match` returns an array of three matches (whole match and hours, minutes), meetingStartHours becomes the part **Before** `:` and meetingStartMinutes becomes the part **After** `:`. It's a debatable elegant way to shorten code by penalizing readability.

Comment: 1or 2 digits`\d` , followed by ":", followed by 2digits. The group of numbers are captured (in parenthesis `()`).

For instance, it matches 9:45 or 12:00

Comment: Whenever you have trouble with understanding a regexp, you can use a tool like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/U0xnSW/2), that will explain you each part of the regexp.

Comment: https://regexr.com/4uq63 also read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Many helpful guide thank you. I asked this before to my dad( who is currently working in a programming) but he said he is too old to know these stuffs haha...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To break down the regex:

```
^(\d{1,2})  // From the beginning of string (^) capture exactly one or two digits (hours)
:           // must be a colon
(\d{2})$    // Capture exactly two digits which also should be the end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Eriks Klotins' answer, if you want to understand and/or create your own regex, you can use websites like this one: [regex101](https://regex101.com/) or this one [regexr](https://regexr.com/).

It's very powerful and well explained.
I have learned to make regex with these and some youtube tutorials.

Comment: This answer is very borderline, as it does not answer the question itself and only contains links to external sites. Therefore the whole thing should be a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.
I tried to do that and delete my answer but I can't comment other answer for now.
I think that my answer is useful for people that needs help with regex thus I will let it.